# Unable to create a constant value of type error with recursive func

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, recursion, hierarchical-data

I have a query that I run that groups employees by there level in the organization hierarchy.  I would like to drill into those result when a user clicks on a group.

Employee table looks like:

```
public class Employee : IEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember]        
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int OrganizationEntityId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [ForeignKey("OrganizationEntityId")]
    public virtual OrganizationEntity OrganizationEntity { get; set; }

}
```

OrganizationEntity table looks like:

```
public class OrganizationEntity : IEntity
{
    [KeyAttribute()]
    [DataMember]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int OrganizationEntityTypeId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [ForeignKey("OrganizationEntityTypeId")]
    public virtual OrganizationEntityType OrganizationEntityType { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual OrganizationEntity Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrganizationEntity> Children { get; set; }
}
```

The code I'm using right now to drill into these groups looks like:

```
private IQueryable<Employee> EmployeesByOrganizationLevel(IQueryable<Employee> employees, int orgEntityId)
    {
        Func<Employee, string> selector = (n => this.FindOrganization(n.OrganizationEntity, orgEntityId));

        var result = employees.Where(o => o.OrganizationEntity.Name.Equals(selector));

        return result;
    }

    private string FindOrganization(OrganizationEntity entity, int orgEntityId)
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else if (entity.Id == orgEntityId)
        {
            return entity.Name;
        }
        else
        {
            return this.FindOrganization(entity.Parent, orgEntityId);
        }
    }
```

The employees that are being passed in are all of the employees I had in my query minus the grouping. For every record I need to traverse the hierarchy and find out if they belong to the orgEntityId passed in so that the other groups aren't included in the result.

When I open up my result variable in watch I see error message:

Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Func`2[Employee]'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

I have very similar code that does the group by for me. The main difference being I'm using a where in my lambda instead of a GroupBy so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error...

Any help would be very much appreciated.

#### UPDATE (Requested by Charles)

Here is the groupBy code I'm using that current works so really the only difference between what I'm doing now is that I'm using a where instead of a group by:

```
private IQueryable<HeadCountRecord> GroupEmployeesByOrganizationLevel(IQueryable<Employee> employees, Enums.HeadCountGroupByGroups organizationType)
    {
        Func<Employee, string> selector = (n => this.FindOrganizationByType(n.OrganizationEntity, (int)organizationType));

        var headCount = employees.GroupBy(selector)
                                .Select((o, index) => new HeadCountRecord
                                {
                                    Id = index + 1,
                                    Grouping = o.Key,
                                    HeadCount = o.Count()
                                }).AsQueryable();

        return headCount;
    }

    private string FindOrganizationByType(OrganizationEntity entity, int entityType)
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else if (entity.OrganizationEntityTypeId == entityType)
        {
            return entity.Name;
        }
        else
        {
            return this.FindOrganizationByType(entity.Parent, entityType);
        }
    }
```

Comment: EF's query provider has to translate your query to SQL.  It can't translate your arbitrary `FindOrganisation` method to SQL  Could you show us the `GroupBy` code that you say works?  I suspect it's being done in memory (on `IEnumerable<T>`) rather than passed as a query expression (to `IQueryable<T>`).

Comment: I'm also struggling to see what you're recursively looking through entities and comparing by name rather than just returning `employees.Where(e => e.OrganizationEntityId == orgEntityId)`

Comment: Update the post with the group by code.

Comment: So what's the question now?

Comment: The employees are linked to one OrganizationEntity in the hierarchy.  OrganizationEntity is a hierarchy table.  So I need to traverse the hierarchy for every employee to ensure they are part of the group that was selected.

Comment: You wrote, "Here is the groupBy code I'm using that current works...", so does that mean you solved the problem?

Comment: No, Charles Mager asked to see it so I added in the post.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework's LINQ Provider will have to translate your query into SQL.  There is no way to convert your arbitrary function into SQL, which is what the error means: the EF provider will only support enumerations or primitive types in a `Where` call.

The `GroupBy` example works because the method selected is `Enumerable.GroupBy` not `Queryable.GroupBy` (you are passing a `Func<string, Employee>`, the `Queryable.GroupBy` extension method would take an `Expression<Func<string, Employee>>`).  This is why the `AsQueryable()` call is required at the end, as your result is `IEnumerable<Employee>`.

This means your second method will cause all `Employees` to be loaded by Entity Framework and the grouping is being done in memory - which isn't ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking a different approach that seems to work well.

Changed the two methods I was using previously to look like:

```
private IQueryable<Employee> EmployeesByOrganizationLevel(IQueryable<Employee> employees, int orgEntityId)
    {
        var results = new List<Employee>();

        foreach (var employee in employees)
        {
            if (this.FindOrganization(employee.OrganizationEntity, orgEntityId))
            {
                results.Add(employee);
            }    
        }

        return results.AsQueryable();
    }

    private bool FindOrganization(OrganizationEntity entity, int orgEntityId)
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (entity.Id == orgEntityId)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return this.FindOrganization(entity.Parent, orgEntityId);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should be aware that this results in the same as the `GroupBy` - you are loading **all** `Employee`s from the database and filtering them in memory, and then there's a potential SELECT N+1 on loading each organisation  This may or may not be a problem, depending how many there are.  The same result could have been achieved by changing `employees.Where` to `employees.AsEnumerable().Where` in your original code.